# Apache vhost always show me the same content on different subdomains

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I have two subdomains on my VPS, i have registered the two subdomains in my DNS pointing to the same IP address.

the version installed is Server version: Apache/2.4.7 for Ubuntu 12.04.

I've enabled the sites with the `a2ensite` command and i have enable the module `vhost_alias`. restart and reloaded many times

## `stable.mydomain.com`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>        
    ServerName stable.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/stable/web

    <Directory /var/www/stable/web>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
            AllowOverride All
            order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

## `beta.mydomain.com`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName beta.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/beta/web

    <Directory /var/www/beta/web>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
            AllowOverride All
            order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

my trouble is pointing my browser to any url always i get the same content and to add more confusion when i execute `service apache2 reload` in the two subdomains i get the content from `beta.mydomain.com` and when execute `service apache2 restart` in the two subdomains i get the content of `stable.mydomain.com`.

I have spent about 5 hours trying to fix this

### update

event i try with the `VirtualDocumentRoot`

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/%1/web"
    ServerName stable.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    <Directory "/var/www/*">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

with the same behavior explained before this update

Comment: -1 - off-topic; see http://serverfault.com

Answer (score -1):

Have you uncommented this line before defining the virtual hosts?

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Comment: that option is deprecated and yes i try with that :( no success

Comment: When adding this line it works for me. Without it I have the same problem as you. The change was not visible immediately and I have to refresh page few times because the incorrect response was cached in browser.

Comment: @rbalent - It is deprecated. I would guess that you're running an older version of apache. See [the 2.4 docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost)